# jQuery Smart Exit Pop up doesn't work in FireFox

Tags: jquery, firefox, jquery-plugins

Using this [jQuery Plugin for Smart Exit Pop Behavior - Exit Popup](http://www.jqueryscript.net/lightbox/jQuery-Plugin-For-Smart-Exit-Pop-Behaviour-Exit-Popup.html) and it works perfectly in Chrome and IE, but nothing in FireFox.

I've got a [test page up here](http://pacelink.com/popUptest/#), and my code is below

Any ideas on what the problem is?

```
<div style="display: none; width:100%; height:100%; position:fixed;background:#9fa1a3; opacity: .4; filter:alpha(opacity=0.8);z-index:999998;"id="exitpopup_bg"></div>

<div id="exitpopup">
  <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="exitpopup"  style="text-decoration:none;">
   <span aria-hidden="true">X</span>
   <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
</a>
 <h1>Wait!!! Before you go...</h1>
<h2>Subscribe the Vortexx mailing list</h2>
<p class="cta">Get exclusive deals, discounts, and exclusive offers!</p>
<form action="//vortexxpressurewashers.us9.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=d291585f9a09bffe246d968b2&amp;id=863cd3e992" method="post" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
<input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="email" id="mce-EMAIL"     placeholder="Enter Your Email Address" required>
<input type="submit" value="Send me deals!" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button">
</form>

<a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="exitpopup">
<span aria-hidden="true" style="font-size:14px;">No, thanks</span>
<span class="sr-only">Close</span>
</a>
  </div>



var last_position = {};
$(document).on('mousemove', function (event) {
if (typeof(last_position.x) != 'undefined') {
    var deltaX = last_position.x - event.offsetX,
        deltaY = last_position.y - event.offsetY;
    if (Math.abs(deltaY) > Math.abs(deltaX) && deltaY > 0) {
        //upward movement       
        if(event.pageY <= 5){
            $('#exitpopup').css('left', (window.innerWidth/2 -      $('#exitpopup').width()/2));
            $('#exitpopup').css('top', (window.innerHeight/2 -     $('#exitpopup').height()/2));
            // Show the exit popup
            $('#exitpopup_bg').fadeIn();
            $('#exitpopup').fadeIn();
        }
    }
}
last_position = {
    x : event.offsetX,
    y : event.offsetY
};
});

$('#exitpopup_bg').click(function(){
$('#exitpopup_bg').fadeOut();
$('#exitpopup').slideUp();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Remark first two if condition and enjoy with firefox also

for Example:

```
*

var last_position = {};
$(document).on('mousemove', function (event) {
//if (typeof(last_position.x) != 'undefined') {
    //var deltaX = last_position.x - event.offsetX,
    //    deltaY = last_position.y - event.offsetY;
   // if (Math.abs(deltaY) > Math.abs(deltaX) && deltaY > 0) {
        //upward movement       
        if(event.pageY <= 5){
            $('#exitpopup').css('left', (window.innerWidth/2 -      $('#exitpopup').width()/2));
            $('#exitpopup').css('top', (window.innerHeight/2 -     $('#exitpopup').height()/2));
            // Show the exit popup
            $('#exitpopup_bg').fadeIn();
            $('#exitpopup').fadeIn();
        }
   // }
//}
last_position = {
    x : event.offsetX,
    y : event.offsetY
};
});

$('#exitpopup_bg').click(function(){
$('#exitpopup_bg').fadeOut();
$('#exitpopup').slideUp();
});

*
```